# How do I fix the log4j vulnerability (Windows)?

Tags: security, log4j

I work in a lab and use a number of Windows VMs to run analysis software. I manage these VMs and am being asked to fix the log4j vulnerability. However, while I have some experience in research computing, I'm really lost as to exactly what I need to do.

I know I need to update to log4j 2.16.0. For next steps, I received instructions from our IT to "make sure that both of the patched API and Core jars are listed in your application’s classpath, which can be done from the command line or by using a manifest file." Unfortunately I don't know what that means.

What are the exact steps I should take to fix the log4j vulnerability on a Windows machine (Windows Server 2019 Datacentre)?

Answer (score 1):

Java applications typically use JAR files that ar zip files with classes. The Log4J.jar file has to be updated. Java applications load these classes at startup, by loading all jar files and classfiles that are specified in the classpath. From the command line that may look like this

Java -cp log4j.jar;myapp.jar my.app.HelloWorld

Its enough to replace the jar file with a new version and restart the application. How the startup looks like for you and where the jar files are located can wildly vary and is impossible to guess without more information

Comment: How do I know which java applications to restart? Is it enough to replace all log4j files with version 2.16.0 and restart the machine?

Comment: In principle that should be enough. But sometimes it's a fight to identify which jar files is actually loaded. Don't leave the old jar in the directory and if possible try to validate the result.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I downloaded log4shell from [here](https://github.com/lunasec-io/lunasec/releases/) and ran `log4shell scan` for all drives. [This guide](https://www.lunasec.io/docs/blog/log4j-zero-day-mitigation-guide/) says any vulnerabilities will be flagged with "identified vulnerable path". I don't see any in the output. Do I need to take any more actions?

Comment: the tool does a file scan for log4j*.jar if your application isn't using log4j version 2 and it can not be found, your job is done. I would still check the startup script to see what jar files are loaded, then you don't have to rely on the tool working 100%

Answer (score 0):

R Greg Stacey
https://github.com/lunasec-io/lunasec/releases/
Apex One indicates a ramsomware

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).